# Could not find a valid gem in `/usr/local/bin`

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm

When running this command for example

```
$ gem install af --no-rdoc --no-ri
```

This error is printed:

```
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem '/usr/local/bin' (>= 0) in any repository
```

Already researched and no link/post/comment was really helpful here. Here some facts:

```
$ gem --version
2.6.14

$ rvm list
=* ruby-2.4.2 [ x86_64 ]

$ gem list
*** LOCAL GEMS ***
(empty)
```

Also when I try to get gem environment vars like that I get this error

```
$ gem env
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::CommandLineError)
    Unknown environment option [/usr/local/bin]
```

Contents of .gemrc is

```
$ cat .gemrc
---
:backtrace: false
:bulk_threshold: 1000
:sources:
- https://rubygems.org/
:update_sources: true
:verbose: true
gem: "/usr/local/bin"
```

Any ideas what this can be? Really weird ...

Answer (score 1):

Meh, silly me, `gem: "/usr/local/bin"` was a bad entry. removing that helped :)